# Using minified HTML in email development

Tags: html, css, email

What (if any) pitfalls would I encounter If I wanted to use minified  HTML code for deployment as an email?

Wouldn't the use of minified code ensure proper rendering accross the majority of different clients given I took the necessary precautions in targeting the clients I intend to support?

More specifically, trying to remedy issues like  closures and white spacing in some versions of Outlook, etc. I live by properly formatted code, so hacking the beauty that is nicely formatted code seems like overkill if I could just minify it, deploy it, and call it a day..

Comment: Does minifying it change any of the CSS (shorthanding it) or remove any modern web unsupported code like `align=""`, `'bgcolor=""` etc? If it does, your answer is NOOOOOOO.

Comment: No, not optimizing it with rewrites or stripping out dead code, more like joining it all in one line of code.

Comment: Minifying is a great idea to avoid Gmail's email clipping and in my experience (working for an email design SaaS business) it will not cause any problems. It's not going to improve rendering anywhere though, just save you space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will cause issues in various email clients.

In my experience, different webmail clients (Yahoo and Gmail in particular) will have issues with lines over a certain length (a couple hundred characters) and start behaving oddly - missing parts of the content, substituting in random characters, etc.

If this were to happen in the middle of HTML, it could be disastrous.

There is no good reason to minify HTML in an email - all of the issues with things like whitespace are well documented by people all over the internet and fixes are easily available.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm afraid this isn't convincing enough. You mention that there's no good reason to minify HTML, but you don't really mention a bad one either. I'm surprised that there's absolutely nothing on the web that discusses the possibility. You mentioned char count, but I doubt that has anything to do with physical HTML line of char count ... right? Does gmail really restrict how much HTML can go on one line? I'd love to check off your answer, but I guess I was looking for more specifics if you have any.

Comment: No, it is actual character count of a line. I have seen this with my own eyes; unfortunately I don't have an example to show.

Comment: @spez86 try it then. It is hard enough designing emails across multiple clients, without minifying it and adding another variable to debug in there. May the force be with you.

Comment: @sevenseacat, damn, this makes me want to do some serious research on whether or not this can work and provide some case studies. Thank you again for the back and forth, perhaps if I ever do succeed in this endeavor, I'll return to this post with my findings.

Comment: @John, I just may. I guess I'm just really surprised that there's very little on the subject on the web. Even if it is bad, I'm surprised there's no one out there talking about how bad it is.

Comment: @spez86 I think because there are so many other things to worry about when it comes to supporting all major clients in html email. Designing email is like walking through a minefield of support/compatibility issues, so most people focus on techniques that maximize client support or workarounds for client quirks. Personally, I don't think minifying the code makes enough of a performance difference to warrant the effort.

Comment: @John, understood, and appreciate your point-of-view. Let's just say I have a client that want's me to do certain things (as we all do) that I know can be avoided if I could do them differently. But, with this clients firm stance on how to do it, I have to resort to asking questions like this on stack.

Comment: @spez86 understood. Regarding client: May the force be with you for that also.

Comment: I actually had a technical reason to minify some of our HTML emails. We have some horrific legacy code through which certain emails are sent, and this legacy code ALWAYS performs a nl2br action on the HTML. So I had to remove all new lines. Now, obviously this corrupts the HTML when it goes over a certain treshold (about 995 chars if I'm not mistaking) because new lines will be added by e.g. Gmail. So I simply added a few new lines with html comments  surrounding the new lines after minifying so the nl2br action wouldn't make things look like shit (<!-- \n -->).

Comment: A good reason to minify an email is to avoid email clipping by Gmail for example. https://fulcrumtech.net/resources/preventing-gmail-from-clipping-your-emails/

Answer (score 2):

Minifying html email is at your own risk. When minifying it does alter the layout, particularly in Outlook. From what I read minifying takes away comments and I need Outlook conditional comments to shape some of my emails. I tested this in Litmus and Email on Acid...both testing platforms display distorted layouts in Outlook. I literally went onto 20 different minify html/css online tools but all of them barely shrunk my file or in all cases distort my layout.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Crush is a minifier that is specifically built to compress HTML for email. The compression ratio won't be as efficient as other minfiers out there, but that's because it's careful about not breaking emails.

https://www.codsen.com/os/html-crush/